# Why the extra bits are added to the kernel version in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: git, embedded-linux

I am cloning the kernel version 4.14.98_2.0.0_ga from git in Ubuntu 16.04 PC.
I get the kernel version as `4.14.98-imx_4.14.98_2.0.0_ga+g5d6cbea`.
But when I do the same in Ubuntu 18.04 PC, I get 5 bits extra added to the kernel version as `4.14.98-imx_4.14.98_2.0.0_ga+g5d6cbeafb80c`. Can anyone please tell why these extra bits are added? Does it depend on the host PC what i am using or is it taking the git tags or commit?

If I give the command `git describe` in 16.04 i get

```
v4.14.98-5985-g1175b59
```

The same command in 18.04 gives

```
v4.14.98-5985-g1175b5961153
```

How can I remove the "61153" from that?

Comment: Do you have the same git versions/configurations? Git abbriviates commit hashes. The length of the abbriviated hash might be different. What command do you use in order to get the version?

Comment: git rev-parse is probably how they grab the version, and it has the --short option to specify a minimum length (core.abbrev) of at least this size.

Comment: @Allen Wind he has cloned the same version. Abbriviation collisions are unlekely.

Comment: @dan1st yep, realize and edited it, but it's the version string of the package after he builds it, right?  So my guess would be a different default value of git's core.abbrev.

Comment: @dan1st the kernel version will be saved in the kernel.release file and is saved by the auto.conf every time the kernel is compiled.

Comment: What's the actual `git` commit you are cloning from? It looks like either *(a)* the two installations use a different length of `--abbrev` (as already speculated above) or maybe *(b)* something already saved the results to a file and now something else is adding a second abbreviated hash to whatever was saved somewhere.

Comment: @tripleee git clone https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx -b imx_4.14.98_2.0.0_ga this is the command i'm using. if the case is (a) where can i check that --abbrev defined?

Comment: `git config core.abbrev` prints its value, if it's defined. `git rev-parse HEAD` prints the current commit in full.

Comment: git config core.abbrev is not defined. and git rev-parse HEAD for thsi i get 1175b59611537b0b451e0d1071b1666873a8ec32. Does --short defines the number of bits appended?

Comment: `--short` simply requests the abbreviated format; out of the box, it figures out a number of hex digits which is reasonably safe within the current repository. With `--short=7` you specify how many hex digits to use instead of the default. (You keep talking about "bits" but you don't get that granularity; each hex digit corresponds to 4 bits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the same identifier just once,

```sh
git describe --abbrev=8
```

To permanently set this repo to always report the abbreviated hash with 8 hex digits,

```
git config core.abbrev 8
```

To set this permanently for all your local repos (unless a repo overrides it separately with a local per-repo configuration) add `--global` to the above command line.

When `core.abbrev` is not set, `git` displays enough hex digits to try to ensure that the printed identifier is safely unique.  This is described in the [`git-config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `core.abbrev`
>
> Set the length object names are abbreviated to. If unspecified or
> set to "auto", an appropriate value is computed based on the
> approximate number of packed objects in your repository, which
> hopefully is enough for abbreviated object names to stay unique for
> some time. The minimum length is 4.